# nested div 100% height with sticky footer

Tags: css, wordpress, sticky-footer, html

I have a `#main` div nested within a container div that I want to fill the page down to the sticky footer.  I've tried several angles, but can't seem to get it to work.  If you don't use firebug, just ask and I'll provide CSS, etc.

Thanks.

site: http://www.dentistrywithsmiles.com

Comment: what browsers do you have to support?

Comment: @Michael Jasper yes, client's choice.  Let's stay on topic here.

Comment: @Jeff I'd like to support all, of course.  But not going to go out of my way to support IE 7 and below...

Comment: it looks fine to me in FF 3.6. how is it not working?

Comment: @Jeff I want `#main` to fill the screen until it tucks behind the filmstrip images in the footer, like at the bottom of the about page [link](http://www.dentistrywithsmiles.com/about).  I'd like this to happen even when, as on the home page, there is no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to do sticky footer many times and I never seem to learn that they are really hard to do. Your situation seems complicated and what you have now doesnt seem half bad.

I think I would use JavaScript to detect page resize and adjust the heights appropriately. Either that, or do something tricky with background images spanning both the footer and #main.

That's probably not what you want to hear but this is a tough problem for only using CSS - tougher than I would care to invest in.

Comment: yeah, @Jeff, I've thought about the js route.  I think I'll end up having to go that way.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm sorry there isn't a better solution. One day maybe, when IE 6 and 7 are distant memories and CSS 4 is widely accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

or css only:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

or

http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-ie8new.htm